# Finding and Echoing out a Specific ID from HTML document with PHP

Tags: php

I am grabbing the contents from google with PhP, how can I search $page for elements with the id of "#lga" and echo out another property? Say #lga is an image, how would I echo out it's source?

No, i'm not going to do this with Google, Google is strictly an example and testing page.

```
<body><img id="lga" src="snail.png" /></body>
```

I want to find the element named "lga" and echo out it's source; so the above code I would want to echo out "snail.png".

This is what i'm using and how i'm storing what I found:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.google.com/";
$page = file($url);

foreach($page as $part){
}
?>
```

Comment: Good luck with that. Google will shut you down quick.

Comment: I'm going to use it to grab content from MY other websites, not from Google. I was just using Google as an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the built-in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class. This class allows you to work with HTML in a structured manner rather than parsing plain text yourself, and it's quite versatile:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

To get the `src` attribute of the element with the id `lga`, you could simply use:

```
$imageSrc = $dom->getElementById('lga')->getAttribute('src');
```

Note that `DOMDocument::loadHTML` will generate warnings when it encounters invalid HTML. [The method's doc page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) has a few notes on how to suppress these warnings.

Also, if you have control over the website you are parsing the HTML from, it might be more appropriate to have a dedicated script to serve the information you are after. Unless you need to parse exactly what's on a page as it is served, extracting data from HTML like this could be quite wasteful.